# What's the difference between ifstream with or without istreambuf_iterator?

Tags: c++, ifstream, istream-iterator

I need to read a binary file (in one go) which contains a header and data. There are different ways to read a file in C++ and I would like to know which one is the fastest and more reliable. I also don't know if `reintrerpret_cast` is the best way to turn raw data into a structure.

EDIT: The header structure doesn't have any functions, only data.

```
ifstream File(Filename, ios::binary);    // Opens file

if (!File)    // Stops if an error occured
{
    /* ... */
}

File.seekg(0, ios::end);
size_t Size = File.tellg();    // Get size
File.seekg(0, ios::beg);
```

This is ifstream WITHOUT istreambuf_iterator

```
char* Data = new char[Size];

File.read(Data, Size);
File.close();

HeaderType *header = reinterpret_cast<HeaderType*>(Data);

/* ... */

delete[] Data;
```

This is ifstream WITH istreambuf_iterator

```
std::string Data;    // Is it better to use another container type?

Data.reserve(Size);
std::copy((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(File)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
          std::back_inserter(Data));

File.close();

const HeaderType *header = reinterpret_cast<HeaderType*>(Data.data());
```

Also found this in the Internet

```
std::ostringstream Data;
Data << File.rdbuf();
File.close();
std::string String = Data.str();

const HeaderType *header = reinterpret_cast<HeaderType*>(String.data());
```

Comment: Does anyone else do a double take when people use PascalCase for C++ variable names?

Answer (score 3):

Reading the contents of the file into a `char*` and then performing `reinterpret_cast` to `HeaderType*` is not a good idea.

From the standard:

> **5.2.10 Reinterpret cast**
>
> ...
>
> 7 An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type<sup>70</sup>. When a prvalue `v` of type “pointer to `T1`” is converted to the type “pointer to *cv* `T2`”, the result is `static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v))` if both `T1` and `T2` are standard-layout types (3.9) and the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`, or if either type is `void`. Converting a prvalue of type “pointer to `T1`” to the type “pointer to `T2`” (where `T1` and `T2` are object types and where the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value. The result of any other such pointer conversion is unspecified.

In your case, if alignment requirements of `HeaderType` are stricter than `char`, you will run into undefined behavior.

If you have the choice, I would suggest.

1. Read the header first.

   ```
   HeaderType header;
   File.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&header), sizeof(HeaderType));
   ```
2. Read the rest of the data based on the value of `header`.

Comment: Do you mean "if the structure has aligned variables" (or is aligned itself)? The struct is not aligned. Is calling `File.read` multiple times much slower than reading it all at once?

Comment: @LHLaurini, I didn't follow your question about alignment. You can read more about it at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Alignment. Regarding multiple calls to `File.read()`, it is slower but I can't tell whether it is significant.

Comment: @R Sahu Thanks, but I know what alignment is.

Comment: @LHLaurini, that wasn't meant to be a slight. Regarding the alignment question, it is the alignment requirements of the class, not the alignment requirements of the variables of the class.

Comment: @R Sahu Sorry, I'm a little (or a lot) dumb sometimes. I think I got it now. (I may disturb you a little more later)

Comment: A `new char[]` guarantees sufficient alignment for any data type.  But of course, global alignment is least of his worries: a binary format on disk will only occasionally correspond to a byte image of a struct in memory.  Reading binary data is a two step process: get the bytes in a buffer in memory, and then parse that buffer into whatever your internal data structure is.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be 'opinion based' and as such is not strictly on-tpoic for SO.

However I don't see the point in using iterators in this case as the `read()` function is more succinct.

However, more importantly, the way you are doing this breaks strict aliasing rules because the alignment in memory of your `struct` is not guaranteed to be in line with a `char` array.

It is always best to cast the address of the `struct` to a `char*` not the other way round:

```
HeaderType header;

File.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&header), sizeof(header));
File.close();
```

Reading data in binary like this is not portable and won't work for complex user-defined types (like `std::string`) so it is preferred to serialize all the data members as a formatted string.

**NOTE:** See docs for [reinterpret_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) for information on type aliasing.

Comment: I don't know... If i use `File.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&header), sizeof(header));` I would need to do multiple read wouldn't I? (there's not only the header in the file) But is there really much difference between reading to the header and reading all the data, then assign a pointer to where the structure is?

Comment: @LHLaurini It is your responsibility to make sure the data you read in is correctly aligned to the memory you have allocated to your structures. How you do that depends on how your data is stored and whether or not portability is an issue (for example if the data came over a network). See R Sahu's answer for an explanation of aliasing rules.

Comment: I am only using `reinterpret_cast<HeaderType>()` because I assume that as long as there's no aligned data it would be safe. I know that if there was aligned data I would need to take care of that. Am I wrong?

Comment: @LHLaurini Whether or not your `HeaderType` shares alignment with a `char` is implementation dependant and it may well work. **BUT** nothing says it won't stop working when you upgrade your compiler or even if you start compiling with different flags.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your anwer. I am aware of packing, but what could happen if I cast from raw data to a struct, and they have different alignment? (EDIT: The compiler doesn't give any warning - it's set to show any warning)

Comment: Regardless of the direction, if you have to use a `reinterpret_cast` here, the code won't actually work (although it may seem to short term).

Answer (score 0):

First, none of the solutions you describe will actually work; the
`reinterpret_cast` should tell you that.  At some point, you'll have to
parse the bytes in the buffer, and insert the extracted data field by
field into your internal data structures.

As for getting the bytes into the buffer as quickly as possible, the
less extra work you do, the better.  The fastest way would be to either
use low level IO (`open` and then `read` under Unix), or even map the
file into memory (`mmap` under Unix).  Of course, this is system
dependent; if you want to use `ifstream` in order to achieve system
independence, then using `istream::read` is certainly the fastest (and
the most logical, all things considered).  Just be sure that the stream
is imbued with the `"C"` locale, as well as being opened in binary mode.

For the record: using the system level functions will transfer the data
directly from the OS into your buffer.  `istream::read` will copy from
an interal buffer in the `filebuf` into your buffer (and use the system
level functions to get the data into your buffer).  The other two will
build an `std::string` object, byte by byte, allocating memory as
needed, since the final length won't be known.

And finally, rather than `new char[size]`, use an `std::vector<char>`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you give a reason to use `std::vector<char>` instead of `new char[size]`?